# Show graph axes when using jqplot library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, jqplot

I am using [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com) for creating graphs using jQuery.

I want to display `Ox` and `Oy` axes in my graph (also, with arrows and some text if possible). How can I do this?

I initialize my graph using:

```
$.jqplot ('graph', [[[1, 2]]], {
    axesDefaults: {
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
    }
   , axes: {
         xaxis: {
             label: "U (V)"
            , min: -5
            , max: 5
            , tickOptions: {
                  formatString: "%#.2f"
                , howGridline: false
                , textColor: '#ffffff'
                , fontSize: '12px'
              }
          }
        , yaxis: {
              label: "I (mA)"
            , min: -10
            , max: 20
            , tickOptions: {
                  formatString: "%#.2f"
                , howGridline: false
                , textColor: '#ffffff'
                , fontSize: '12px'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It looks like this:

> [image]

I imagine something like this:

> [image]

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JDu5q/10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial explains it better 
http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/canvas-overlay.html

Here is sample : http://www.datafilehost.com/d/f4b6a7b5

You will need canvas plugin.

```
$.jqplot ('graph', [[[1, 2]]], {
     axesDefaults: {
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
    }
   , axes: {
         xaxis: {
             label: "U (V)"
            , min: -5
            , max: 5
            , tickOptions: {
                  formatString: "%#.2f"
                , howGridline: false
                , textColor: '#ffffff'
                , fontSize: '12px'
              }
          }
        , yaxis: {
              label: "I (mA)"
            , min: -10
            , max: 20
            , tickOptions: {
                  formatString: "%#.2f"
                , howGridline: false
                , textColor: '#ffffff'
                , fontSize: '12px'
            }
        }
    },
    canvasOverlay: {
            show: true,
            objects: [
               {dashedVerticalLine: {
                    name: 'bam-bam',
                    x: 0,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    dashPattern: [16, 12],
                    lineCap: 'round',
                    yOffset: '20px',
                    color: 'rgb(66, 98, 144)',
                    shadow: false
                }}
            ]}
});
```

Comment: The tutorial is good, but I would like you to modify [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/JDu5q/10/) so the axes to be added (`Ox` on `y=0` and `Oy` on `x=0`). Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use JSFiddle ...as you will need http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js plugins you will have to download & implement them.I have updated the code that should work .

Comment: I added the code in the jsfiddle, but no axes are shown: http://jsfiddle.net/JDu5q/11/ Can you provide full HTML page, then?

Comment: you quietness forced me to write sample.I have added link in post.http://www.datafilehost.com/d/f4b6a7b5

Comment: @IonicăBizău Have you seen the uploaded solution. If anything wrong tell me.